# Making a screen on storyBoard where UIViews are replacing eachother on button Click?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, storyboard

I am new to swift and storyboards. I am making a screen where I want to place different UIViews with different components on one another. How to achieve this? And view them on button click. Should i use subviews or handle their visibility>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In storyboard you can not create separate views. So simply create UIViews in a controller with proper frame and make its outlet in controller.m file.

YES you have to use subviews and handle there visibility.  Initially hide all UIViews. Now based on button tapping event show required view and hide all other views.